# TSQL pivot columns to flatten results

Tags: t-sql, pivot, flatten

My current query returns results in the below layout;

reference    name      telephone
123         jon doe     012345600
123         jon doe     079852015
111         paul schoon 0147258369
147         joe schmoe  025847896

How could i return them so they are flattended for a csv in the following layout?

reference,    name,      telephone 1, telephone 2
123,         jon doe,     012345600, 079852015
111,         paul schoon, 0147258369,
147,         joe schmoe,  025847896,

Any ideas appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do a one time job to show somebody for some report purpose or something. The easiest way is

> Run you query in SQL Server Management Studio, simply right click on the results header - Save results as -> choose a .csv file.

Alternatively if you are looking some more repeat job with manual execution you can BCP or SQLCMD utilities. Microsoft Reference urls [bcp Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility) , [sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility)

If you want just a query to return this. You should add these commas your self. Though you have to add first row for column names manually as so you can use it directly.

```
    SELECT "reference, name, telephone 1, telephone 2"
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [reference] + ", " + [name] + ", " + [telephone 1] + ", " + [telephone 2]" FROM [YOurTableName]
```

> By the way, you have tagged your question under piot tag though from your
>   description it doesn't look like you are trying to pivot. Please
>   confirm.

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply. I am looking to schedule an automated routine. There is a pivot option that will help to turn the last two rows into columns based on Telephone 1 and Telephone 2.